# Is there a PyTorch equivalent of tf.custom_gradient()?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, automatic-differentiation

I am new to PyTorch but have a lot of experience with TensorFlow.

I would like to modify the gradient of just a tiny piece of the graph: just the derivative of activation function of a single layer. This can be easily done in Tensorflow using tf.custom_gradient, which allows you to supply customized gradient for any functions.

I would like to do the same thing in PyTorch and I know that you can modify the backward() method, but that requires you to rewrite the derivative for the whole network defined in the forward() method, when I would just like to modify the gradient of a tiny piece of the graph. Is there something like tf.custom_gradient() in PyTorch? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

**1. Modifying the `backward()` function:**
As you already said in your question, [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) also allows you to provide a custom `backward` implementation. However, in contrast to what you wrote, you do *not* need to re-write the `backward()` of the entire model - only the `backward()` of the *specific* layer you want to change.
Here's a simple and nice tutorial that shows how this can be done.

For example, here is a custom `clip` activation that instead of killing the gradients outside the `[0, 1]` domain, simply passes the gradients as-is:

```py
class MyClip(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, x):
        return torch.clip(x, 0., 1.)

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad):
        return grad
```

Now you can use `MyClip` layer wherever you like in your model and you do not need to worry about the overall `backward` function.

---

**2. Using a `backward` hook**
[pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) allows you to attach hooks to different layer (=sub `nn.Module`s) of your network. You can [`register_full_backward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.register_full_backward_hook) to your layer. That hook function can modify the gradients:

> The hook should not modify its arguments, but it can optionally return a new gradient with respect to the input that will be used in place of `grad_input` in subsequent computations.

Comment: This is super helpful, good to know that I can write forward() of just a single layer